# Code 404 when calling APILayer currency conversion service

Tags: java, request, http-status-code-404, vert.x

I need to send a request to APILayer.
In the browser it works perfectly.
https://api.apilayer.com/currency_data/convert?to=USD&from=EUR&amount=5&apikey=

I want to send the request using Vertx.

```
    HttpClientOptions options = new HttpClientOptions();

    options.setLogActivity(true);
    options.setDefaultPort(8080);

    HttpClient client = routingContext.vertx().createHttpClient(options);

    client.request(HttpMethod.GET,"api.apilayer.com/currency_data/convert?to="+to+"&from="+from+"&amount="+amount+"&apikey=", response -> {
        System.out.println("Received response with status code " + response.statusCode());
        int code = response.statusCode();
        if (code == 200) {
            response.bodyHandler(bufferResponse -> {
                JsonObject httpResult = bufferResponse.toJsonObject();
                System.out.println("Received HTTP response with body " + httpResult);
            });
        } else {

            response.bodyHandler(bufferResponse -> {
                String httpResult = "{null}";
            });
        }

    }).putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "").end();
```

I always get error 404.
Anyone knows how to get the response ?

Thank you

Comment: You might want to remove the API key from your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClientOptions options = new HttpClientOptions();

options.setLogActivity(true);
options.setDefaultPort(443);
options.setSsl(true);

HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient(options);

client.request(HttpMethod.GET, "api.apilayer.com", "/currency_data/convert?to=USD&from=EUR&amount=5&apikey=")
  .compose(HttpClientRequest::send)
  .onSuccess(response -> {
    System.out.println("Received response with status code " + response.statusCode());
    int code = response.statusCode();
    if (code == 200) {
      response.bodyHandler(bufferResponse -> {
        JsonObject httpResult = bufferResponse.toJsonObject();
        System.out.println("Received HTTP response with body " + httpResult);
      });
    } else {

      response.bodyHandler(bufferResponse -> {
        System.out.println("Received HTTP response with body " + bufferResponse.toString());
      });
    }

  }).onFailure(Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

The HttpClientOptions were incorrect. I fixed the configurations in the above code snippet and it worked on my local.